# show an error message after getting the value of input field dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

I have a form where I am adding the records and I have an option to edit them. I have newly added dropdown which is mandatory. So I have used validators on that field which gives field is required error after submitting the form, it works fine for adding new records. For edit record I have condition, the field is newly added so for existing records the field will be empty and when user tries to update the record it should give the required error for new field and wouldn't allow to save. because the field is mandatory I have set it to 0 initially so the required error is never thrown. I want to write a condition like
if field.value==0 then show error how can I do that for reactive forms in angular?

My edit form HTML

```
                        <div class="col-xl-7">
                            <span data-qa="largedepositconstraintedit">
                                <label data-qa="edit-large-deposit-constraint"
                                for="edit-ldc-Description">LDC</label>
                            <span>
                            <label class="fdl-select">
                                <ddrm-validated-input
                                [control]="newHoldSchedule.get('ldcForm')"
                                [path]="'ldcForm'">

                                <select class="form-control"
                                id="largedepositconstraint-edit"
                                data-qa="largedepositconstraint-select"
                                formControlName="ldcForm"
                                required>
                                    <option
                                        id="largedepositconstraint-edit-{{type.value}}"
                                        *ngFor="let type of ldConstraint"
                                        [value]="type.value"
                                        [selected]="type.value == row.ldcAmt"
                                        required>{{type.value}}
                                    </option>
                                </select>
                            </ddrm-validated-input>
                            </label>
                            </span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
```

ts file:

```
this.newHoldSchedule = this.formBuilder.group({
              ldcForm: [(row.ldcAmt != null ? row.ldcAmt : ' ')'), Validators.required],
});
```

I want a condition if type.value==0 then show an error message. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you create stackblitz please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Custom Validators in Angular. Google it for more information.
But I leave you a custom validator function according to your condition:

```
equalToZero(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors {
  return control.value !== 0 ? undefined : {
      equalToZero: true
  };
}
```

You only have to integrate it to your control for example:

```
this.newHoldSchedule = this.formBuilder.group({
    ldcForm: [(row.ldcAmt != null ? row.ldcAmt : ' ')'), [Validators.required, this.equalToZero]],
        });
```

And then, catch it in your HTML for example:

```
<div *ngIf="newHoldSchedule.get('ldcForm').errors?.equalToZero">
  <small>You cannot use 0 as value.</small>
</div>
```

Comment: You think this should be an answer? you should have add it as comment.

Comment: Thank you so much for sample custom Validator. I had to change some conditions but it worked. Thanks